# Traverse using numpy.where with 2 indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having this kind of array: **v = [1, 2, -1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -10, -10, -10]**.
My assignment is to create another array with the indices of the elements, where a change of sign has been made. For the example above, the new array should be **v2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]**. I have been given the indication to use numpy.where, but I can not figure it out how to traverse the array with 2 indices, for something like:

```
for i in range(len(v) - 1):
    if v[i] * v[i - 1] < 0:
        v2.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
out = np.nonzero(np.diff(np.sign(v)))[0]

# or with np.where
# out = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(v))!=0)[0]
```

output: `array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])`

Intermediates:

```
np.sign(v)
# array([ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1])

np.diff(np.sign(v))
# array([ 0, -2,  2,  0, -2,  2, -2,  0,  0])

np.nonzero(np.diff(np.sign(v)))[0]
# array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
```